# How to aggregate multiple Rasterstacks into one

Tags: r, spatial, raster

I have several `Rasterstacks` created from several time series Netcdf files. I would like to aggregate these to mean/median and the associated 95% confidence intervals or Standard Deviation statistics. The output would be a single `Rasterstack` of the same dimensions representing a mean/median/stdev taken across all `Rasterstacks`.

I tried using `overlay` function but it doesn't seem to work. Here is a reproducible example:

```
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
library(ncdf4)

r <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10)
r1 <- init(r, fun=runif)
r2 <- init(r, fun=runif)
r3 <- overlay(r1, r2, fun=function(x,y){return(x+y)})
r4 <- overlay(r1, r2, fun=function(x,y){(x*y)} )
r5 <- overlay(r1, fun=sqrt)

#create rasterstacks
s1 <- stack(r1, r2,r3)
s2 <- stack(r3, r4,r5)
s3 <- stack(r4, r5, r2)
s4 <- stack(r1, r4, r3)

z<-overlay(s1, s2, s3, s4, fun=function(a,b,c,d){return(median(a,b,c,d))} )
Error in (function (x, fun, filename = "", recycle = TRUE, ...)  : 
cannot use this formula, probably because it is not vectorized
```

Comment: @Pascal reproducible example updated. Error returned with the overlay call to `Rasterstacks`

Comment: `s <- stack(s1, s2, s3, s4); mean(s); calc(s, sd); calc(s, median)`?

Comment: Or do you expect layer-wise mean/etc.? i.e. do you want 3 means, with the first corresponding to the mean across the stacks' first layers, the second the mean across their second layers', etc.?

Comment: Yes, layer wise means. In the above example, the output rasterstack would have three layers, where layer 1 would be a median for r1,r3,r4,r1, layer 2 will be a median for r2,r4,r5,r4, and layer 3 for r3,r5,r2,r3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Edit: This post provides three approaches to the problem. Fastest for large RasterStacks is the third approach, which coerces the stacks to an array and performs calculations on that.*

---

#### Approach 1: overlay

I assume you want layer-wise statistics, i.e., you want your result to be a `RasterStack` with three layers, the first being the median of the fours stacks' first layer (i.e. the median of rasters `r1`, `r3`, `r4` and `r1`), the second being the median of the four stacks' second layer (median of `r2`, r4`,`r5`, and`r4`), and so on.

You can `Vectorize` functions `mean`, `median`, and `sd` to make this possible:

```
overlay(s1, s2, s3, s4, fun=function(...) Vectorize(median, 'x')(list(...)))

## class       : RasterBrick 
## dimensions  : 10, 10, 100, 3  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
## resolution  : 36, 18  (x, y)
## extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
## coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
## data source : in memory
## names       :    layer.1,    layer.2,    layer.3 
## min values  : 0.01763912, 0.01018932, 0.24531431 
## max values  :  0.9933407,  0.9050321,  1.4268951
```

Replace `median` with `mean` or `sd` as required.

---

#### Approach 2: uberlay

The above approach seems to slow down quite a bit with larger rasters. Maybe I'm doing it wrong... An alternative is to call `mapply` more directly:

```
uberlay <- function(..., fun) {
  fun <- match.fun(fun)
  L <- lapply(list(...), unstack)
  stack(do.call(mapply, c(FUN=function(...) calc(stack(...), fun), L)))
}
```

Pass the RasterStacks to `...` and the function to `fun`.

```
uberlay(s1, s2, s3, s4, fun='median')

## class       : RasterStack 
## dimensions  : 10, 10, 100, 3  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
## resolution  : 36, 18  (x, y)
## extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
## coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
## names       :    layer.1,    layer.2,    layer.3 
## min values  : 0.01763912, 0.01018932, 0.24531431 
## max values  :  0.9933407,  0.9050321,  1.4268951
```

---

#### Approach 3: superduperlay

@Joe [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34603287/how-to-aggregate-multiple-rasterstacks-into-one/34604525?noredirect=1#comment56955472_34604525) that the `uberlay` approach takes around an hour with his data. For big stacks, it can be faster to coerce the stack to an array (or, e.g., a `data.table`) and perform calculations on that.

Let's create some fake data using @Joe's dimensions:

```
library(raster)
library(abind)

nc <- nr <- 17
nl <- 5829

s1 <- stack(replicate(nl, raster(matrix(runif(nr*nc), nr))))
s2 <- stack(replicate(nl, raster(matrix(runif(nr*nc), nr))))
s3 <- stack(replicate(nl, raster(matrix(runif(nr*nc), nr))))
s4 <- stack(replicate(nl, raster(matrix(runif(nr*nc), nr))))
s5 <- stack(replicate(nl, raster(matrix(runif(nr*nc), nr))))
```

First, coerce the stacks to matrices and bind to a three-dimensional array.

```
A <- abind(as.matrix(s1), as.matrix(s2), as.matrix(s3), as.matrix(s4), as.matrix(s5), 
           along=3)
```

Now apply your function to margin `1:2`, adjust the dimensions and transpose, then stack back into a `RasterBrick`:

```
z <- apply(A, c(1:2), median) # substitute median with desired function
dim(z) <- c(nr, nc, nl)
z <- apply(z, c(1, 3), t)
b <- brick(z)
```

The whole process, including creating the array, takes just over 30 sec on my system for `median` and `sd`. For `mean`, you can take advantage of `colMeans`, speeding things up to under 3 sec. We can wrap this all up into a function for convenience:

```
superduperlay <- function(..., fun) {
  require(abind)
  require(raster)
  fun <- match.fun(fun)
  L <- list(...)
  A <- do.call(abind, c(lapply(L, as.matrix), along=3))
  if(as.character(match.call()['fun'])=='mean') {
    A <- aperm(A, c(3, 1, 2))
    z <- colMeans(A)
  } else {
    z <- apply(A, c(1:2), fun)
  }
  dim(z) <- c(nr, nc, nl)
  z <- apply(z, c(1, 3), t)
  b <- brick(z)
}

system.time(my_mean <- superduperlay(s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, fun='mean'))
##    user  system elapsed 
##    2.68    0.04    2.72 

system.time(my_median <- superduperlay(s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, fun='median'))
##    user  system elapsed 
##   31.75    0.06   31.92
```

Each object is a `RasterBrick` (can be coerced to `RasterStack` if needed, with `stack()`), e.g.:

```
my_mean

## class       : RasterBrick 
## dimensions  : 17, 17, 289, 5829  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
## resolution  : 0.05882353, 0.05882353  (x, y)
## extent      : 0, 1, 0, 1  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
## coord. ref. : NA 
## data source : in memory
## names       :    layer.1,    layer.2,    layer.3,    layer.4, ... 
## min values  : 0.19478752, 0.14775996, 0.15108237, 0.14281812, ... 
## max values  :  0.8388662,  0.8577153,  0.8396123,  0.7781535, ...
```

Comment: Have run your solution 2 on my 5 stacks of dims : 17, 17, 289, 5829  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers); resolution  : 0.44, 0.44  (x, y). Takes up to an hr to run these which is reasonable  for such large data.

Comment: @Joe - Thanks for reporting back. For rasters of that size it might be better to coerce to e.g. a data.table, perform your calculations, and then coerce results back to raster.

Comment: for example?  I'd be keen to test system times among the different solutions. Approach 3 is 0.5 times slower than approach 2

Comment: Post updated. I've combined my second solution with this one, and deleted the `superlay` example (referred to as Approach 3 in @Joe's comment above) since it was essentially identical to the `uberlay` version.